# How to pass values through an intent using a method?

Tags: android, android-intent

My goal is to pass values through an intent after the MyCountDownTimer runs out of time. This is the code that I've got so far. WHere do I place the putExtra ?

```
@Override
    public void onFinish() {


        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);
        textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);




}
```

here's where the method is being used in my activity

```
if (textCounter==null){

                myCountDownTimer.onFinish();
            }
```

NEW EDIT:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId()== R.id.retry){

            Bundle extras1 = getIntent().getExtras();
            whichTest = extras1.getInt("whichTest"); //NUllpointerException


            if (whichTest == 1){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Retry.this, Test1.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }

            if (whichTest == 2){
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Retry.this, Test2.class);
                startActivity(intent1);}
```

....

```
@Override
    public void onFinish() {


        Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);

           if (textCounter.getContext().equals(Test1.class)){
               whichTest = 1;
               retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
           }
        if (textCounter.getContext().equals(Test2.class)){
            whichTest = 2;
            retryIntent.putExtra("whichTest",whichTest);
        }
        textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);
```

Comment: Don't `Intent` in `onFinish`, simply `Intent` when the user clicks a button to "retry".

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Intent.putExtra(string key, value)`

Ex.

```
retryIntent.putExtra("MY_COUNTDOWN_TIMER_NAME", "George");
```

you can retrieve them in the new activity by doing

```
string george = getIntent().getExtras().getString("MY_COUNTDOWN_TIMER_NAME");
```

check the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20double[])) for more information on what kind of objects can be extras.

edit:

The flow of intents.

Activity 1 creates an intent, it puts extras into said intent, and starts activity 2.

Activity 2 gets the intent that started it using `getIntent()`. It then uses `getExtras()` to retrieve all the extra data passed with the intent. Finally it gets values from the extras by key.

If try to use `getIntent().getExtras()` from an activity that wasn't started like activity 2 was this way you will get a null pointer exception.

If you aren't sure if Activity 2 was started with or without extras you can always check if `getIntent().getExtras()` returns `null`

Comment: The onFinish method is in another class. Sorry for leaving that out.

Comment: that shouldn't matter

Comment: Can you check out my new edit and tell me why I get a nullpointerexception? I commented the line of code that had it.

Comment: Please make sure you follow the correct flow of intents. Your flow of activities seems kind of erratic and is very confusing. Check the edit

Comment: What I did was this: I have a MyCountDownTimer class which holds the onFinish() method. The Test1 class borrows the onFInish() method and passes it to the Retry Activity. I declared what values to pass in the MyCountDownTimer class(the class that holds the onFinish() method). In the new edit, I only included the snippets from the Retry Activity, and the MyCountDownTimer Class

Answer (score 0):

You would put that line between the two you have already written in the onFinish() method:

```
Intent retryIntent = new Intent(textCounter.getContext(), Retry.class);
retryIntent.putExtra(name, value);
textCounter.getContext().startActivity(retryIntent);
```